# How to fit a classification model with Image-Arrays?

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I was trying to build a model that would distinguish honey bees from bumble bees based on the input image.

My plan was to build a classification model that will take an image-array as an input and will return either 'honey bee' or 'bumble bee.
I thought I could fit the model with honey bee images, that's where I got stuck.

This is as far, as I've got:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


link = 'https://www.dadant.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/ABJ-Extra-December12-256x256.jpg'
img = Image.open(link)
x = np.array(img)
y = ['honey bee']

logreg = LogisticRegression()

logreg.fit(arr, y)
```

`x` returns a 3d array which can't be past to `logreg`.

Is there any way I could fit the model? Maybe, turn the arr into a dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

[Fitting a model with images](https://github.com/shukkkur/Predict-Species-from-Images)

Full project on building a image classification model